# How to Make <br> Tag work Inside Title "br" in tooltip class , bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a table column where I am displaying 3 vehicle parts and rest of them on pop up , I am using foreach loop inside of the title. now the problem is the "br" tag I am using is displayed as it is ..

[image: This is the output]

```
<td>
    <div class="d-inline-block" data-toggle="tooltip" title="
    @foreach ($vehicle_part->eligibleModels as $eligibleModel)
        {{ $eligibleModel->vehicleModelNumber->vehicle_model_number }}  <br>
    @endforeach">
        @foreach ($vehicle_part->eligibleModels->take(3) as $eligibleModel)
            {{ $eligibleModel->vehicleModelNumber->vehicle_model_number  }} <br>
        @endforeach
        @if ($vehicle_part->eligibleModels->count() > 3)
            ...
        @endif
    </div>
</td>
```

I am using bootstrap.

Here is the JavaScript ,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

I have tried putting it inside Not working ..

```
{{ $eligibleModel->vehicleModelNumber->vehicle_model_number <br>}}
```

Comment: `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({html:true});` will not encode html tags.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I can't thank you enough man ..  worked ...